# replace symlink with file on write

Tags: symbolic-link, inotify

Is there a way to make a file system/server replace a symlink with an actual file on write? Something like inotify would work, but as far as i can tell, I cannot run code before the write operation is performed?

I'm thinking I would like to implement this at the file system level. However, most use cases the files are served over webdav or smb if that is a better place.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#In_computer_storage

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not really clear. I think what you want is to replace a link by a file once you have all the content?

When you open a softlink, it opens the destination, so you just cannot do that. You have to first `unlink(filename)` then `open(filename, O_CREAT | ...)`.

However, if the idea is to have the file ready, then you want to save the file in the same folder with a different name (i.e. `"<filename>.tmp"`). Then once ready you `unlink(filename);` and then `rename(filename + ".tmp", filename);`.

That way, the period of time when the file doesn't exist is very small (assuming your process doesn't get cutoff "at the wrong time"). Most system that copy files use that technique: `scp`, `rsync`, etc.

Comment: No, I think Mokubai's comment is correct. I am trying to build a limitted COW functionality into a system that does not use COW file system.